# Insert data column by column in the database-Moodle

Tags: php, database, moodle

I'm trying to insert data into a database but i can't seem to add data to other columns in the table. It just adds it to the same 2 rows.

The **process.php** page:

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/config.php');

global $DB;

$name = required_param('name', PARAM_TEXT);
$comment = required_param('comment', PARAM_TEXT);

$record2 = new stdClass();
$record2->name = $name;
$record2->displayorder = '10000';

$record3 = new stdClass();
$record3->name = $comment;
$record3->displayorder = '10000';

// Insert one record at a time.

$lastinsertid2 = $DB->insert_record('faculty', $record2);
$lastinsertid3 = $DB->insert_record('faculty', $record3);

if(!$lastinsertid2)
{
    echo "Could not insert";
}
else
{
    echo "Successful";
}

?>
```

This is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
    Name    <input type="text" size="60" name="name"/>
    Comment <input type="text" size="60" name="comment"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

My question is, how can i modify `$lastinsertid2 = $DB->insert_record('faculty', $record2);` so as to be able to add data column by column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for that should be

```
$record2 = new stdClass();
$record2->name = $name;
$record2->comment = $comment;
$record2->displayorder = '10000';

$lastinsertid2 = $DB->insert_record('faculty', $record2);
```

I would suggest keeping this page open for reference

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API

Comment: Can you write the complete codes please? I'm still getting an error. Isn't it supposed to be 
        $record2 = new stdClass();
 $record2->name = $name;
 $record2->comment = $comment;
 $record2->displayorder = '10000';

Comment: I modified it according to your codes but i'm getting this error message:Field 'comment' doesn't have a default value
INSERT INTO faculty (name) VALUES(?)
[array (
0 => 'Max',
)] 
Error code: dmlwriteexception

Comment: Okay that's probably because Moodle doesn't know about the comment field. But I don't have enough time to help unfortunately. You will need to add the comment field to the install.xml file in your local plugin and then either uninstall and reinstall the local plugin, or add an upgrade.php file to add the new column. Most of this is explained here https://docs.moodle.org/dev/XMLDB_editor